# Save word document opened in delphi olecontainer

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole

I have a word document open in an ole container.  I would like to select all the text (Ctrl-A) then copy to the clipboard without using keystrokes.

The second feature desired is the ability to save any changes made to the document.

Comment: After further digging the following code worked for the save feature.

procedure TBCSWordTstC.SaveObjectToFile1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vWord: Variant;
const wdFormatDocumentDefault=16;
begin
  SaveDialog1.Title := 'Select File To Save';
  SaveDialog1.DefaultExt := '*.*';
  if SaveDialog1.Execute(Handle) then
  begin
    vWord := OleContainer1.OleObject;
    vWord.SaveAs(SaveDialog1.FileName, wdFormatDocumentDefault);
  end;
end;

Comment: possible duplicate of [dumping word document ( \*.doc) to Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289836/dumping-word-document-doc-to-text)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code help you:

```
uses ComObj, Clipbrd;
...
var
  Word : OLEVariant;
begin
  Word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');

  // If you do not want to see word, set it to false.
  Word.Visible := False;

  //Open the word document.
  Word.Documents.Open('C:\myDocument.doc');

  //Select all.
  Word.ActiveDocument.Select;

  //Copy to Clipboard.
  Word.ActiveDocument.Range.Copy;

  //Close the document.
  Word.ActiveDocument.Close;

  //Quit word.
  Word.Quit;

  //Free.
  Word := unassigned;

  //Now you can paste the text from clipboard.
  Memo1.PasteFromClipboard;
end;
```

Comment: ActiveDocument is not recognized.  The document was activated with Ole Container.